# How to redefine \hat{H} as \hat{\cal H}?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, accents

I would like to redefine `\hat{H}` as `\hat{\cal H}` only for this particular letter (for Hamiltonian symbol in physics). Thank you very much.

Comment: I should note that `\cal` has been deprecated since 1994 and that `\mathcal{H}` is the preferred syntax.

Comment: Whether or not it's possible, macro-ing away the syntax in a way such as requested is a *bad idea* in any language. Ultimately it is just a form of code obfuscation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well I guess that there are two ways of proceeding here:

- Use the "find and replace" tool of your editor to replace all the matches of `\hat{H}` by `\hat{\mathcal{H}}` or
- a bit more appealing... in the preamble of the document define a new command, say `\newcommand*{\hham}{\hat{\mathcal{H}}}`. Then use the "find and replace" tool of your editor to replace all the matches of `\hat{H}` by `\hham`

A MWE would be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand*{\hham}{\hat{\mathcal{H}}}

\begin{document}

The relation,
\[\hham\psi_n = E_n\psi_n\]
is valid for every  eigenstate $\psi_n$ of the Hamiltonian $\hham$.
\end{document}
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you. I have wondered if there is any possibility to do so without having to overwrite all \hat{H} in the document using find/replace tool. But the second way seems quite suitable for me. Thank you again.

Comment: @HonzaZubáč: Yes, the newcommands are very helpful to define "structures" that you will use over and over through the document, specially because if you want to change all of them to another symbol, e.g. `\mathcal{H}` to `\mathbb{H}`, you need to do it once... at the definition. Changing subject, I'd like to remind you that you are invited to vote up the useful answers, and "check mark" the one you found accurate to your needs. Cheers.

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way is to define a new command `\hatH`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*{\hatH}{\hat{\mathcal{H}}}
\begin{document}
\[ \hatH \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

A redefinition of `\hat` is far more complicate, because of TeX rules in math. `\hat` expands to `\mathaccent` that does not parse its base as "argument" but as `<math field>`. The latter can be a math symbol or a sub formula. This cannot be parsed by a macro argument in a 100% compatible manner.

An approximation is the following example that tests the cases that an `H` or `{H}` is following `\hat`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\old@hat}{}
\let\old@hat\hat
\newcommand*{\hatH}{\old@hat{\mathcal{H}}}
\renewcommand*{\hat}{%
  \@ifnextchar\bgroup{%
    \new@hat
  }{%
    \@ifnextchar H{%
      \expandafter\hatH\@gobble
    }{%
      \old@hat
    }%
  }   
}     
\newcommand*{\new@hat@H}{H}
\newcommand*{\new@hat@arg}{}
\newcommand*{\new@hat}[1]{% 
  \renewcommand*{\new@hat@arg}{#1}%
  \ifx\new@hat@arg\new@hat@H
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {% 
    \hatH
  }{%
    \old@hat{#1}%
  }%
}   
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[ \hatH \hat H \hat{H} \hat x \hat{x} \hat{ab} \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Shouldn't `\cal H` be `\mathcal{H}`?

Comment: @egreg: `\cal H` is shorter and it is inside a sub formula, because the curly braces are *not* argument braces. `\hat` expands to `\mathaccent` that expects a `<math field>` that can be a symbol or a sub formula.

Comment: Deprecated commands such as `\it` or `\cal` are not guaranteed to be in all classes.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks, I have already changed the answer accordingly (and extended with an approximated redefinition of `\hat`).